# how to resolve async await inside a unit test - javascript

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, lambda

I have a lambda for which I'd like to write unit tests for. I'm using async await but I'm getting issues with resolve promises. I'd like to test the different conditions, how can I write the test to resolve and stop seeing the timeouts?

Thanks in advance.

> Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure
>   "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.

--- unit

```
describe('tests', function() {

    describe('describe an error', () => {
        it('should return a 500', (done) => {
            handler('', {}, (err, response) => {
                expect(err.status).to.eq('failed')
                done()
            })
        })
    })

});
```

-- handler

```
export const handler = async (event, context, callback) => { 

 return callback(null, status: 500 )

})
```

Comment: Which unit testing framework are you using ?

Comment: Does `handler('',{}, (err, response) => {expect(err.status).to.eq('failed')}).then(() => done() )` actually works?

Comment: Sinon, Chai and Mocha. I'd like to stub out the test with Sinon, will this work?

Comment: _"I'm using async await"_ `await` does not appear at code at Question. What is expected result?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try following:

```
describe('tests', function() {
    describe('describe an error', () => {
        it('should return a 500', (done) => {
            await handler('', {}, (err, response) => {
                expect(err.status).to.eq('failed');
            })
            done();
        })
    })
});
```

or

```
describe('tests', function() {
    describe('describe an error', () => {
        it('should return a 500', async () => {
            const error = 
              await handler('', {}, (err, response) => Promise.resolve(err))
            expect(error.status).to.eq('failed');
        })
    })
});
```

Anyway, I think, you need to `await` your async handler...

Comment: Hi @dhilt, thanks for the answer. I went with the second approach as I think it needs to resolve at some point.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the framework you're using there're multiple ways to handle `async` unit tests.

For example if you're using `Jasmine`:

1) You can use `Spy` to replace your `async` callback with a static function, that way it won't be `asyncronous` and you can mock the return data. This can be useful for unit testing where you don't need to test dynamic async operations (unlike with integration tests).

2) There is also real async support documentation that can be found here: [Asynchronous Support](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support)

3) You should always use `beforeEach()` with `async` tests as that's where you define your `done()` function on describe level

Comment: Sinon, Chai, Mocha is what I'd like to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can increase the timeout of your test.

```
describe('tests', function() {

    describe('describe an error', () => {
        it('should return a 500', (done) => {
            handler('', {}, (err, response) => {
                expect(err.status).to.eq('failed')
                done()
            })
        }).timeout(5000)
    })

});
```

The  [`timeout`](https://mochajs.org/#timeouts) method accepts the time in ms. Default is 2000

Answer (score 1):

Use [Blue Tape](https://github.com/spion/blue-tape). It is a thin wrapper around Tape, a simple, productive test framework recommended by Eric Elliott among others.

Blue Tape handles any tests that return promises automatically.

All methods using `async`/`await` return promises per the ECMAScript specification.

Here is what it looks like

```
import test from 'blue-tape';

test('`functionThatReturnsAPromise` must return a status of "failed"', async ({equals}) => {
  const {result} = await functionThatReturnsAPromise();
  equals(status, 'failed');
});
```

You can even write synchronous tests this way if you simply include the `async` keyword.

Note how there is no use of `done` or `end` or any of the other boilerplate and noise associated with asynchronous testing in most frameworks.

I strongly recommend you give it a try.